# Can't write a querySelectorAll on html file

Tags: jquery, selectors-api

I can't write the total numbers of divs that have the same class name, when I try to do it it just print [object NodeList]. How can I get the amount of div classes and print them on the document? Thanks a lot, here's the code:

`<script>
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#container .foo')
    document.write(elementos);
</script>`

Comment: You need to use .length, elementos.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.length` property:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('#container .foo').length;
```

using jquery:

```
 $('#container .foo').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** to get the **[length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** of container ,foo

```
$("anycontainer").find('#container .foo').length;
```

or

```
 $('#container .foo').length;
```